# Slide to layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm apparently not phrasing it correctly to get any accurate results on Google. I want to be able to slide right/left to go to another layout. What is the proper term I should be using when trying to find an example of how this is done?

Comment: You are probably looking for the [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)

Comment: Yeah, I can see why I didn't guess that. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Meh, ok. I always feel bad for posting 5 second answers. :P :)

Comment: If it answers my question and gives me an example: that's all I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).